# Not able to use `fzero()` function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, nonlinear-functions

I am new to Matlab. I am trying to solve a non-linear equation using this inbuilt Matlab function called `fzero()` but it's not giving me the results.

The main file goes like

```
A = 5;
B = 6;
C = 10;

eq = equation (A, B, C);

fzero(@(x)eq);
```

The other function file is:

```
function eq = equation (A, B, C)

syms x;
eq = A*x.^2 + B*x + C*(asinh(x)) ;
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error using fzero (line 118)
The input should be either a structure with valid fields or at least two arguments to
FZERO.

Error in main (line 7)
fzero(@(x)eq);
```

Could someone help me with this?

**EDIT:** 
WHen I specify the check point as `0`, it returns me the following error.

Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

```
Error in fzero (line 308)
    elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)

Error in main (line 7)
fzero(@(x)eq, 0);
```

Comment: Hey, you changed your question! It looks like you are having trouble understanding the way *sym* works. You should spend some time, and if you can't figure it out ask another question.

Comment: @Mikhail No, I just edited the question and added the later part. It still gives me an error when I specify the check-point.

Comment: Note that you can also solve symbolic equations with Matlab. Make sure to check `doc solve`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Matlab hangs when I use this function. My original equation is too lengthy. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. For a start, `fzero` is for finding numerical roots of a non-linear equation, it is not for symbolic computations (check the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html)), so get rid of `syms x`. The correct way to call `fzero` in your case is a as follows:

```
A = 5;
B = 6;
C = 10;
eq = @(x) A*x^2 + B*x + C*(asinh(x));
x0 = 0; % or whatever starting point you want to specify
x = fzero(eq,x0)
```

Comment: Ok, but it's still not clear. Could you please tell me how would I add 2 functions. Actually my problem is not this problem. 

Let's suppose, I have.

`fun1 = @(x)sin(cosh(x))` and
`fun2 = @(x)cos(cosh(x))`. Now how can I add these two functions like `fun3 = fun1 + fun2` and solve `fun3` using fzero. Please help

Comment: I answered your question. If you have a different question, please ask it in a separate thread, otherwise it becomes confusing. And make it clear and explicit: I don't really understand what you mean. You can only solve one function/equation at a time. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a guess, *x0* point

```
fun = @sin; % function
x0 = 3; % initial point
x = fzero(fun,x0)
```

Comment: Okay, I did that. Now, it returns another error. I have edited the question. Can you please recheck?

Comment: The main problem is mixing `fzero` with `sym`. `fzero` is a numerical function, not a symbolic one.